# pandas rearranging experiment data

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

So I've looked at some other posts, but they didn't quite help. I'm not new to python, but I'm relatively new to pandas and this has me stumped as to how to accomplish it in any manner that's not horribly inefficient. The data sets I've got are a little bit large and have some extraneous columns of data that I don't need, I've got them loaded as dataframes but they basically look like this:

```
+---------+---------+--------+-------+
| Subject |  Week   |  Test  | Value |
+---------+---------+--------+-------+
|       1 | Week 4  | Test 1 |     4 |
|       1 | Week 8  | Test 1 |     7 |
|       1 | Week 12 | Test 1 |     3 |
|       1 | Week 4  | Test 2 |     6 |
|       1 | Week 8  | Test 2 |     3 |
|       1 | Week 12 | Test 2 |     9 |
|       2 | Week 4  | Test 1 |     1 |
|       2 | Week 8  | Test 1 |     4 |
|       2 | Week 12 | Test 1 |     2 |
|       2 | Week 4  | Test 2 |     8 |
|       2 | Week 8  | Test 2 |     1 |
|       2 | Week 12 | Test 2 |     3 |
+---------+---------+--------+-------+
```

I want to rearrange the dataframes so that they look like this:

```
+---------+---------+--------+--------+
| Subject |  Week   | Test 1 | Test 2 |
+---------+---------+--------+--------+
|       1 | Week 4  |      4 |      6 |
|       1 | Week 8  |      7 |      3 |
|       1 | Week 12 |      3 |      9 |
|       2 | Week 4  |      1 |      8 |
|       2 | Week 8  |      4 |      1 |
|       2 | Week 12 |      2 |      3 |
+---------+---------+--------+--------+
```

If anyone has any ideas on how I can make this happen, I'd greatly appreciate it, and thank you in advance for your time!

Edit: After trying the solution provided by @HarvIpan, this is the output I'm getting:

```
+-----------------------------------------------+
|  Subject     Week  Test_Test 1  Test_Test 2   |
+-----------------------------------------------+
| 0        1  Week 12            5            0 |
| 1        1   Week 4            5            0 |
| 2        1   Week 8           11            0 |
| 3        2  Week 12            0           12 |
| 4        2   Week 4            0           14 |
| 5        2   Week 8            0            4 |
+-----------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: You might be able to find something useful in the [reshaping doc pages](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reshaping.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [`df.pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html).

You should be able to get the desired outcome with:
`df.pivot_table(index=['Subject','Week'], columns='Test', values='Value')`

Comment: Not sure if it's something I'm doing wrong, but using that code gives me ValueError: Length of passed values is 12, index implies 2

Comment: Sorry, it should be `df.pivot_table`, which supports multiindexing for the rows. I've corrected it above.

Answer (score 0):

You need get dummy variable for column `Test` with `pd.get_dummies(df[['Test', 'Value']], 'Test').mul(df['Value'], 0)]` with multiplication of their `Value` before concatenating them back to your original `df`. Then `groupby` `Subject` and `Week` before summing them.

```
pd.concat([df.drop(['Test', 'Value'],1), pd.get_dummies(df[['Test']], 'Test').mul(df['Value'], 0)], axis=1).groupby(['Subject', 'Week']).sum(axis=1).reset_index()
```

Output:

```
   Subject   Week       Test_ Test 1   Test_ Test 2 
0        1   Week 12               3              9
1        1   Week 4                4              6
2        1   Week 8                7              3
3        2   Week 12               2              3
4        2   Week 4                1              8
5        2   Week 8                4              1
```

Comment: Not sure if I did something wrong, but the above code gave me this:
`   Subject     Week  Test_Test 1  Test_Test 2
0        1  Week 12            5            0
1        1   Week 4            5            0
2        1   Week 8           11            0
3        2  Week 12            0           12
4        2   Week 4            0           14
5        2   Week 8            0            4`

Comment: @DanP, it is hard to understand with the text in comment, can you edit your question with proper code formatting showing what output are you getting?

Comment: Sorry about that, I edited the original question with the output after trying the code you provided above.

Comment: Are you sure, you have copied my code to the word? I think you are missing `groupby(['Subject', 'Week']).sum(axis=1).reset_index()`, which is already in my code.

Comment: I noticed I made an error when I loaded in the original dataframe and accidentally entered the first column as [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2] instead of [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2] like it should have been. It worked now, thanks so much for your help!

Comment: @DanP, glad it worked. Consider upvoting and [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) the answer.